# EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)

Tags: android, mixpanel, roaming

my watch is trying to download updates, (android 8.1)
but I can see in mixpanel the following error:

error android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)

Any ideas what is happening??

Thanks a lot
Manu